# What do you call this in IOS?

Tags: ios

I Study iOS alone.

You can find the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XW8z.jpg)

when I clicked Button left side open option page.

I wonder this function name.

Plz tell me what do u call this function??

Comment: Another recommended https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu

Comment: That icon is often commonly referred to as a "hamburger button."

Comment: It is commonly/popularly known and called `slide-out menu`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out [**swrevealviewcontroller**](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController):

> A UIViewController subclass for revealing a rear (left and/or right) view controller behind a front controller, inspired by the Facebook app, done right!